# Angular 4 Observable always running error

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I am making a custom observable to update an image url on a button click. The buttons that trigger the image change and the element to change are in separate components.

I am using a service to update which button is clicked and which image to display. I am currently using an Observable to update the image when one of the buttons are clicked. I am completely new to observables and I'm trying to understand why my Observable is running the error function every time? My Observable runs the next() function but also always runs error() and never runs again. Is there something Im missing here?

data.service.ts:

```
`import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';


 @Injectable()
 export class DataServiceService {
   navOptions = []
   main_description = ""
   music_description = ""
   social_description = ""
   imgArr = [
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/748838/pexels-photo-
      748838.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb",
      "https://a.vsstatic.com/mobile/app/concerts/chance-the-
      rapper.jpg",
       "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?
      q=tbn:ANd9GcQoS3rbeRhL2cok8--
      b4l4BPT0k62Z5_pt55_01ogS9iNXgt3pD",
      "https://a.vsstatic.com/mobile/app/concerts/chance-the-
      rapper.jpg"
   ]
   currentImg = this.imgArr[0]
   bannerImg: Observable<any>;

   constructor() { }



   getBannerImg(): Observable<any>{
      return Observable.create((observer)=>{
         observer.next(this.currentImg)
         observer.error('error'), //always runs
         observer.complete()   

       });


   }


 }
```

and index.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataServiceService } from '../data-service.service';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from 
'@angular/animations';


@Component({
 selector: 'app-index',
 templateUrl: './index.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./index.component.css'],
 animations: [
   trigger('bannerState',[
     state('expanded', style({
       height: "700px",
     })),
     state('collapsed', style({
       height: "300px",
     })),
     transition( 'expanded <=> collapsed', animate('100ms ease-out'))
   ])

 ]
  })
 export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
 navState = {
   bannerState: "expanded"
 }

 navOptions = [
   {
     title: "SHOWS",
     link: "/shows"
   },
   {
     title: "MUSIC",
     link: "/play"
   },
   {
     title: "CONTACT",
     link: "/contact"
   },
   {
     title: "SOCIAL",
     link: "/about"
   },
 ]

 currentImg;

 main_description = "The time has come | Enjoy the musical stylings 
 of Ray Ward JR"
 music_description = "Explore Music"
 social_description = "Get Affiliated"

 constructor(private dataservice: DataServiceService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.retrieveData()
   this.passDataToService()
 }

 passDataToService(){
   this.dataservice.navOptions = this.navOptions;
   this.dataservice.main_description = this.main_description;
   this.dataservice.music_description = this.music_description;
   this.dataservice.social_description = this.social_description;
 }

 retrieveData(){
   this.currentImg = this.dataservice.currentImg;

   this.dataservice.getBannerImg().subscribe(
     (x) => {console.log('on next %s', x)}, //runs only first time
     (e) => {console.log('onError : ', e)}, //always runs
     ()=>{}

   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you wish to do is to subscribe only once to the observable received from `getBannerImg` and get the new value of that observable every time it changed. If so, you should use [behaviorSubject](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/subjects/behavior_subject/index.html) instead of Observable.

Saying that, I'll try to explain what currently happens in your code:

Your `getBannerImg` function creates an Observable that for every subscription does the following actions, one right after the other:

1) invokes the next function of the provided observer with the value `this.currentImg`

2) invokes the error function of the provided observer with the value `error`

3) if no error was previously invoked for this subscription, invokes the complete function of the provided observer with no value. Since we had an error in step 3, this code will do nothing.

Then, in `retrieveData` you are subscribing to the observable with the observer

```
 (x) => {console.log('on next %s', x)}, //runs only first time
 (e) => {console.log('onError : ', e)}, //always runs
 ()=>{}
```

So, for this subscription, you will see the following 2 lines:

```
on next https://images.pexels.com/...
onError :  error
```

You did not provide your HTML code but if the button click triggers `retrieveData` function,  you will see the same 2 lines as the output for every subscription (unless you will change `currentImg` between the subscriptions and then the value of the first line will be change).